# Ways to support new languages without releasing each time?

Tags: android, internationalization

I want to slowly support new languages for my android app.  But I don't want to cut a new release for every new language I support.  What are ways I can do this?  I looked into the qordoba sdk but there isn't a way to register for an account there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest those steps

- Create a folder to your app.
- Add xml files each one is a supported language.
- Create a language class with static Strings/arrays and make their default is strings.xml file in values.
- Create your own xml parser to get language from its file.
- When the app starts get the current language of the phone and if it exists in your folder, parse that file. If it doesn't not exist, use the default values of strings from your language class.
- If everything is ok in the file, make your static variables refer to the new parsed Strings.
- When you support new language, just add its xml file to your app folder.

Hope this is useful.